# What makes Appcelerator Titanium project compilation time so long?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I've started a new project and measured the time from when I hit play to start compiling until I see it on the iPhone simulator (simulator already open - so to no calculate the time it takes to boot it up).

At first compilation it took 1:56 minutes. Since it is the first time and I'm guessing it does things it wouldn't the for  future compilation I gave it another go, this time compilation time went down to 1:15 minutes.

Anyone who knows me and follows my posts knows that I like comparing platforms on many aspects. So I did. I compared with the new kid on the block - ReactNative. React initial compilation took 32 seconds. Second compilation took 10 seconds.

It is important to mention that ReactNative project is run from xCode while Titanium scripts do pre build stuff. But also if looking at a react xCode project and Titnaium xCode project you see that Titanium has a lot more "baggage" in the project.

I know I can use LiveView - but that's not always what you want or need.

Compilation time is important to the development process. So I'm wondering why Titanium compilation takes so long, and if there is any way to shorten that time (significantly) ?

Answer (score 2):

If you think it's slow now, you should have seen it before. :)

There are a ton of things that happen every time you build your app. I've optimized much of the build process, but there is a bunch of things I can do to speed up the logic leading up to the build process.

Every time you build, we have to validate your session, we have to scan for all Xcodes, iOS simulators, etc., we have to check like 30 things to see if we need to force a rebuild, and so on. Plus if you have an Alloy app, the build has to trigger the Alloy compiler. Depending on the type of app, we parse the AST of all your code as many as 3 times.

There's a lot things we can do to speed things up. There's a lot of things we can cache. There's a lot of subprocessing that we can inline. There's a lot of unnecessary disk I/O. There's a lot of unnecessary AST parsing.

The good news is I'm actively working on improving this. Builds are going to get much, much faster.

Comment: I have seen it before. it definitely improved! question: when writing alloy project and using liveview - does the alloy transpiler also run on every save?

Comment: @developer82 Yeah, I believe so, but don't quote me. It's been a long time since I played with LiveView and I mostly tested with classic Titanium apps.

Comment: @ChrisBarber the reason I'm asking is because LiveView seem to render very fast. Maybe it's something that can be leveraged when doing compilation for debugging - and "full" compilation when releasing - of course I don't know the in's and out's of how it works and probably wrong... but just a thought.

Comment: Yes, Alloy does a full compile on every change. Alloy can compile specific files as well, but LiveView hasn't been updated to take advantage of that: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18597

Answer (score 1):

Titanium takes longer at the first build or after a change to `tiapp.xml`. In that case we fully rebuild the Xcode project. Indeed in the case of ReactNative the Xcode project is just there, but this also means you have to manage Xcode settings yourself.

Every following compile should be a few seconds. Alloy projects take a bit longer because atm it still compiles the full Alloy project. This should become incremental in the next version as well.

Please check your logs. It should report at some point if it is doing a full rebuild and why.

Comment: Thanks. any tips to speed it up a bit?

Comment: Well, like I asked - could you check your logs to see the reason why it is doing a full rebuild when it actually shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project 1 minute for an "empty" project is very long. And recompilation without any code changes should take not that long (a couple of seconds in my case).

Which SDK version are you using to test? There was a bug which could be related (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1340 "Alloy selective compilation broken since ALOY-1332
").

Are you using Appc Studio or command line tools to compile?

Have a look at this old article:
http://jolicode.com/blog/alloy-selective-compilation-for-an-even-faster-titanium-development-process 
they did some testing about compilation time, too.

Comment: I was working against SDK 5.2.x - but it was always the case (even before trying out that version). I'm compiling from Appcelerator Studio.